# how to find location through gps on my phone

Tags: android

I actually wrote the below code on the onclick method of a button,but it is giving null pointer exception,plzz help

```
public void submit(View v)
{

LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location= locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double mesg1=location.getLatitude();
    double mesg2=location.getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: Did you had the permissions?

Comment: Yes access_fine_locations one ,had it.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html

You should register a listener for location updates - see requestLocationUpdates() method.

Also add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission to your Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

hey follows few steps to get proper and accurate current location.
This way provided you current location both by interent as well as gps.

Step 1.

Put this class in your code. 
GetCurLocation.java

```
public class GetCurLocation implements LocationListener,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

public static LocationClient mLocationClient;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
public static LocationManager locationmanager;
float accuracy = 500;
Activity context;
boolean getLocRegularly = false;
int interval = 1000;
float Radius;
GoogleMap gmap;

SetOnLocationFoundListner OLF;

public interface SetOnLocationFoundListner {
    public void onLocationFound(Location location, boolean getLocRegularly,
            GoogleMap gmap);
}

public void RemoveUpdates() {
    try {
        if (mLocationClient != null)
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        if (locationmanager != null)
            locationmanager.removeUpdates(LocUpByLocMgr);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

/*
 * radius should be in meters
 */
public GetCurLocation(Activity activity, int interval,
        boolean getLocRegularly, GoogleMap gmap,
        SetOnLocationFoundListner OLF, float Radius) {
    this.OLF = OLF;
    this.gmap = gmap;
    this.context = activity;
    this.getLocRegularly = getLocRegularly;
    this.interval = interval;
    this.Radius = Radius;
    if (servicesConnected()) {
        mLocationClient = new LocationClient(context, this, this);
        mLocationClient.connect();
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(interval);
        mLocationRequest
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(interval);
    }

    locationmanager = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria cr = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cr, true);
    locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, interval, 0,
            LocUpByLocMgr);
}

private boolean servicesConnected() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,
                (Activity) context, 0);
        if (dialog != null) {
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    try {
        Location location = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        Log.e("testing",
                location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude()
                        + "," + location.getAccuracy());
        if (location.getAccuracy() < Radius) {
            OLF.onLocationFound(location, getLocRegularly, gmap);
            locationmanager.removeUpdates(LocUpByLocMgr);
        } else
            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    try {
        if (location.getAccuracy() > Radius) {
            Log.e("testing LC", location.getAccuracy()
                    + " Its Not Accurate");
        } else {
            Log.e("testing LC", location.getAccuracy() + " Its Accurate");
            try {
                OLF.onLocationFound(location, getLocRegularly, gmap);
                if (!getLocRegularly) {
                    mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
                    locationmanager.removeUpdates(LocUpByLocMgr);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

android.location.LocationListener LocUpByLocMgr = new android.location.LocationListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        try {
            if (location.getAccuracy() > Radius) {
                Log.e("testing LM", location.getAccuracy()
                        + " Its Not Accurate");
            } else {
                Log.e("testing LM", location.getAccuracy()
                        + " Its Accurate");

                try {
                    OLF.onLocationFound(location, getLocRegularly, gmap);
                    if (!getLocRegularly) {
                        mLocationClient
                                .removeLocationUpdates(GetCurLocation.this);
                        locationmanager.removeUpdates(LocUpByLocMgr);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

}

Step 2.

implement setonlocationfoundlistener in class where you want current location,

and declear one more method in your oncreate and after you will get one location found method and it return location and you can get location.getlatitude and location.getlongitude.

```
GetCurLocation gcl = new GetCurLocation(activity, 0, true, null, this,
                2000);
```

Step 3. make permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

thats all. thanks

Comment: Actually ,i want to get the location on the onclick method of a button so i just wanted to know how to actually call this GetCurLocation.java class in my code ,Please guide as I am new to android.I just want to share my code which I have written in my onclick method.

Comment: And please see my code which I have posted,and tell the problem in that code.

Comment: I'll check your code and  let you know.In my code you need to call that getlocation method  in your onclick and you have more option like you get location reguraly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void loc1(View v)
{

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
               String longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
               String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "latitude",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "longitude",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
};

// getting GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

// check if GPS enabled
if (isGPSEnabled) {

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location != null) {
             String   longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
                String latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        } else {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (location != null) {
                      String  longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
                     String   latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
                } else {
                      String  longitude = "0.00";
                     String   latitude = "0.00";
                }
        }
}


}
```

Comment: Please see this ,I have added this in my code but it is not showing any output.I have added only one permission in my code and that is of access_fine_locations one.